# TreeView not showing checked nodes from function call to OnSelectedNodeChange in a Web Forms projet

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I just want to show checked node's values and I've got the following code regarding that

**Default.aspx**

```
 <asp:Literal ID="Message" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="56px" 
            OnClick="Select_Change" />
      <div>
     
          <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" 
              ShowCheckBoxes="All"
              OnSelectedNodeChanged="Select_Change"
              >

          </asp:TreeView>
      </div>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            //These variables and methods create a hierarchy of the folder structure.
            var latestDirectory = DirectoryList().First().FullName.ToString();
            
            this.directoryFiles = DirSearch(latestDirectory);
            this.directoryArray = dirArray;
            this.directoryString.Text = latestDirectory;

            ListDirectory(TreeView1, latestDirectory);
        }

protected void Select_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = "selected nodes \n";
            
            foreach(TreeNode item in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
            {
                message += item.Text;
            }
            Message.Text = message;
        }
```

When I click the button, it just shows the generic "selected nodes" with nothing after it, even after selected node(s). Any ideas as to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected item, is just a item, you want the collection of checked values.

this:

```
    For Each tN As TreeNode In TreeView1.CheckedNodes
        Debug.Print("Sel node = " & tN.Value & "," & tN.Text)
    Next
```

or

```
    foreach (TreeNode tN in TreeView1.CheckedNodes) 
    {
        Debug.Print("Sel node = " & tN.Value & "," & tN.Text);
        message += tN.Value.ToString() + "->" + tN.Text + "| "; 
    }
```

So, is your code beind setting both a value and text? Or perhaps you are just setting the .Value. It not clear how the TV is being loaded up?

**EDIT =======================================================**
Lets take an full example. We have this:

```
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"
            ShowCheckBoxes="All">
        </asp:TreeView>

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="347px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadTree();
    }

    void LoadTree()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Tx " + i, "Vx" + i));
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sChoices = "";
        foreach (TreeNode tN in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
            sChoices += "(" + tN.Value + "," + tN.Text + ") ";

        TextBox1.Text = sChoices;
    }
```

So, we run and check the first two, say like this:

[image]

Comment: I just want to get the value of whatever is inside of the selected node, so I'm using .Text for each node in the list, but even using the second foreach you displayed above, there's still nothing being showed besides the hard-coded "selected nodes ".  Why would the selected nodes not be registered on check?

Comment: You want to use checkedChanged event. That event fires when you check a box. NodeChanged event does not fire - that event is for when you click on a node - not the check box. However, from either event, the checked list should be valid.

Comment: I just changed the event to TreeNodeCheckChanged and it's still not registering checked nodes. Am I missing something in my Page_Load? I'll update to include as it's just not making sense.

Comment: You probbably should just check the ones you want, and then have a button outside of the TV to click on and thus check the collecton that way. From what I can find, JUST checking on the box does NOT trigger the event. It only triggers when you click on the node. So in theory, you check box, and then click the node. So, your code is probably not triggering? My bad - you had the better event.

Comment: Ah, more info. As  general rule, check boxes does not fire nor post back. Clicking on the node DOES trigger the event, and MOST cases that is code to expand the TV. In your case, if the nodes don't have child nodes, then you check the boxes you want, place a separate button on the page - now check the checked collection in that button code - it should be fine.

Comment: No worries! In default.aspx I have a button at the top that calls the Select_Change method, is that what you’re talking about implementing?

Comment: See my example code posted - I posted the markup + working code. As you can see, we really do not need nor use any TV events - we don't need them.

Comment: I do have child nodes and further down, but it was all the if(!IsPostBack). Thank you very much!